# Android native code building with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to buikd a Android native module inside the Android build system using NDK.
My module builds properly with out any error while building with Android module make command. 
But when I try the use NDK build setup I am facing problem with android system include files.
My module structure is :

```
android
       |
       external
              |
              MyModule
                     |
                     jni --> Android.mk
                     mysharedobj --> Android.mk
```

My Native module includes many android includes such as

```
#include <JNIHelp.h>
#include "android_runtime/AndroidRuntime.h"
#include <gui/Surface.h>
#include <gui/ISurface.h>
```

With the help of NDK docs i was able to resolve the include errors, but i am facing somre  error,
eg:

```
jni/com_my_module_NativeInterface.cpp:3:21: fatal error: JNIHelp.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

-->For resolving the JNIHelp.h include error, i had added the following line in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../libnativehelper/include/nativehelper
```

After this again one more error,

```
jni/../../../libnativehelper/include/nativehelper/JNIHelp.h:27:24: fatal error: cutils/log.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

--> To solve above error i had modified Android.mk

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../libnativehelper/include/nativehelper \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../system/core/include \
```

After this again one more error

```
/home/user/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/uio.h:18:8: error: redefinition of 'struct iovec'
jni/../../../system/core/include/cutils/uio.h:33:8: error: previous definition of 'struct iovec'
```

How to build a native module successfully that uses android system include files?
Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure, but try to put the flag **-DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H** on your **LOCAL_CFLAGS**:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LOCAL_LDLIBS` instead of adding ndk dependencies to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`. The example below is from my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-arm/usr/lib -L$(LOCAL_PATH) -llog -lz -lm
```

Checkout docs to see which libs you should add for your needs.